# Access Expression methods in IronRuby

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

This code works fine in C#:

```
Expression.Lambda(LambdaBody);
```

But none of the methods for building AST seem to visible from IronRuby. I required Microsoft.Scripting.Core and Microsoft.Scripting libraries. Do I need something else?
Here is the IronRuby code:

```
require 'C:\reorganize\software\ironruby-1.0rc3\ironruby\bin\microsoft.scripting.core'
require 'C:\reorganize\software\ironruby-1.0rc3\ironruby\bin\microsoft.dynamic'
require 'C:\reorganize\software\ironruby-1.0rc3\ironruby\bin\microsoft.scripting'
include Microsoft::Scripting::Ast
p Expression.Lambda(lambda_body) #i have already constructed the lambda body
```

gives:

```
undefined method `Lambda' for #<TypeGroup: Microsoft::Scripting::Ast::Expression, Microsoft::Scripting::Ast::Expression[TDelegate]> (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1
```

Comment: The System.Linq.Expressions.Expression class is in the System.Core assembly. Do you have referenced that?

Comment: Im talking about Microsoft::Scripting::Ast::Expresstion

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misspell `Expression` in your code? (You wrote Express_t_ion in your comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are two `Expression` classes in the Microsoft.Scripting.Ast namespace: a generic and a non-generic one. Try forcing the non-generic one using `.of()`:

```
Expression.of().Lambda(lambda_body)
```